# Do (giant) apps really contain only one Timer object?

Tags: oop

I have recently heard this sentence from my previous teacher, but on the internet I didn't find any helpful article or something like that. Can somebody comfirm this, or this is just not true at all?

He said that the reason of it is that the Timer objects are "resource intensive."

Comment: I work on a giant app, but we just make calls to the OS, who manages the timers for us.  I have no idea why he thinks an app would only have one timer though. _someone_ has to manage multiple timers regardless, and there's no reason to think the app would do a better job of it than the OS.

Comment: Clearly whether this is true or not would depend on many different things, such as your definition of a *giant* app, the OS it's being run on, what the specific app is doing and whether it would be able to use just a single timer or not, and other factors. There's no generic answer to your question. Why didn't you ask the teacher that said it for more information about it? They're the one that said it, and they're best suited to explain why they did so and where you can get more information.

Comment: Unfortunately this teacher doesn't teach me anymore and I can't talk with him (I would do it if I could). Thanks for the answers, now I have some ideas why did he say it, but maybe it isn't true nowadays (he is kinda old, for instance he programmed in cobol - perhaps at that time, when he learnt it, it was true).